# Angular pass callback to promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I pass the callback to be handled by a promise as a parameter to the calling function?  For example, I have

```
$scope.caller = function() {
    $http({...}).then(successCallback(response) {
        ...
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        ...
    });
}
```

How can I pass an anonymous function to `$scope.caller()` to be evaluated when the promise completes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass your function as a parameter to $scope.caller.

```
$scope.caller = function (somefunc) {
     $http(..).then(somefunc));
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this ?

```
$scope.caller = function(onFinal) {
    $http({...}).then(successCallback(response) {
        ...
        onFinal();
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        ...
        onFinal();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add another `then` to the callback chain:

```
$scope.caller = function(callback) {
    $http({...}).then(successCallback(response) {
        ...
        return response; // always return in your Promise to allow chaining
    }, function errorCallback(response) {
        ...
    }).then(callback);
}
```

When you call `$scope.caller`, pass your callback as a parameter:

```
$scope.caller(function(response) {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to defer, resolve and return your promises in a 'Factory' or 'Services' file.
Here is a very straightfoward way of handling promises. 
Note that '$scope.caller = function() {...}' is the same as 'function caller() {...}'.
Always have your API calls in the 'Factories' or 'Services' file.

Refer to example below :

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# caller.factory.js
# 'app.foo.caller' refers to your directory structure i.e. app/foo/caller/caller.factory.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.caller', [])
        .factory('callerSvc', CallerService);

    /* @ngInject */
    function CallerService(
        $log,
        $q,
        $http,
        $window,
        $state,
        logger,
        session,
        utils,
        API_CONFIG) {

        var ENDPOINTS = {
            CALLERS: '/v1/callers'
        };

        /**
         * @ngdoc service
         * @name app.foo.caller
         * @description Caller management
         */
        var service = {
            caller: caller
        };

        /**
         * @ngdoc method
         * @name caller
         * @description Returns all callers
         * @methodOf app.foo.caller
         * @returms {promise} caller or null if not found
         */
        function caller() {
            var q = $q.defer();

            var request = utils.buildAuthRequest( session, 'GET', ENDPOINTS.CALLERS );

            $http(request)
              .success(function (callers) {
                  q.resolve(callers.result);
              })
              .error(function (error) {
                  logger.error('CallerService.caller > Error ', error);

            return q.promise;
        }
    }
})();

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# caller.module.js
# 'app.foo.caller' refers to your directory structure i.e. app/foo/caller/caller.module.js

(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.foo.caller', [
        ]);
})();
```